# ImageButton resizes automatically in gridlayout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm asking this (propably) pretty easy question since I can't figure it out by myself and googling in for more then an Hour doesn't give me proper results.
So the question is: How can I make my items(generally those are only 16 image buttons) so they can stay in scale (comparing to gridlayout) when my picture is really large (So in short way: I load 16xImages as src on buttonImages, each Image is 640x640, and I want to have those 16 buttons in grid layout scaled comparing to grid layout width/height and column/row count). I hope this is possible to write in XML since I don't want to refactor my java code :/

Ps. I'm newbie to Android programmig

Ps2.Here is my GridLayout with button example , but it's completly wrong :/

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4"
    tools:context=".GridXMLActivity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Tx1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/restart"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/clear"
        android:id="@+id/But1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="but1"

        />
```

[EDIT]
I've even made such layout , but there are some problems. 1st is that my grid layout doesn't scale at all!(So when I take screen with lower or higher resolution it won't fit). That's why I wanted to make this button some kind of resizeable (in this screen each button has width and height at 60sp which I know it shouldn't)
Another problem is that I'm working on button backgrounds and I wanted to make it src.
Genereally I want to achive same thing like on the screen , but making it other/more flexible way (So the resolution and orientation won't affect my gui and sizes of it's element). If you need whole XML file I'll post it here but it's a bit mess since I've copy-paste 16 times Image Button
[image]

Comment: Your question can be interpreted a couple of ways. If my answer is not the question you are asking, try using screenshots or ascii art to illustrate what you want

Comment: I've edited my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something to scale, keeping aspect ratio and you have one dimension set to `match_parent`, the other must be `wrap_content`.

So, presuming you want the button to always fit the width but stay at the correct aspect:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... />
```

To make all items fit in grid rather than all items fit their images, you should use weight. Weight with grid layout requires the support library before API21

```
<GridLayout ...
    android:columnCount="2">

    <ImageButton
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    ...
```

Comment: Okay , since noone response , I'll write this really short what I want to do:
I chose width and height of my grid layout , and I want all this 16 ImageButtons to fit into width & height of my gridlayout, no matter how big is my image and my Gridlayout